# Remove leading special characters from multiline string

Tags: java, regex

Working on XSS vulnerability in which I have a requirement to remove all the leading special characters only. No need to remove the special characters at the end or in between. Alphanumeric is allowed but no special characters at the beginning.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
        
public static void main(String args[])   {  
String str=   "**$*****Important****\n"
             + " document is not uploaded \n"
             + "%3Cscript%3E";    
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", " ");  
System.out.println(str);  

 }  
}
```

The code above gives output as:

> Important

But the expected output is:

> Important**** document is not uploaded 3Cscript%3E

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to anchor the regex to the beginning of the string with `^`: `"^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+"`

Comment: That said, there should be frameworks and libraries that take care of this for you, so I'd not recommend rolling your own. You may easily miss corner cases and details.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Looking for multiline as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+", " ");
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for the modified question.

Comment: Good. I would say then it probably needs to be marked as the accepted answer, since, iirc, multiline was *always* the requirement

Answer (score 2):

There are three changes you need to make:

1. Anchor the match to the beginning of the string with `^`.
2. Match more than one special character with `+`.
3. Replace the matched substring with `""` instead of `" "`:

```
    str = str.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+", "");
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. But this fails in multiline. Is there a way to sort that? Example :        `String str= "*******Important 123 And here we go for 50$ **** \n"
             + "%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%29%3C%2Fscript%3E "; '      Here this fails to remove the secondline's %.

Comment: @GS1 That should be an edit to the question; your question only has a single string, too. That said, look into the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE).

Comment: @GS1 Please post a new question. Now that you edited your question my answer will no longer make sense to future visitors.

Comment: Sure will take care of this in future. New in posting questions. Thank you